# commenting in an xml file

Tags: android, xml

The xml file in an android project project is typically formatted like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_dialog"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click to display a dialog"
    android:onClick="onClick" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Is it possible to comment out just one or two parameters within a tag? For example, can I comment out just the line with `android:layout_width` or two lines with `android:layout_width and android:layout_height` in the above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, XML does not permit you to embed comments inside tags.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-comments

Comment: if I want to change just one line in the above sample code to check it's effects, is there any other easy way to do this, such as the `//` of C? Is it possible to make just the "<Button ... />" part a comment?

Comment: The easiest way is simply to cut the line, so that you can test and then paste it back in. You could also just make a comment below the tag and paste the attribute in there temporarily.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit :**

Sorry,  Comments cannot occur within tags, e.g. `<tag ></tag>.`

Comment: I don't think that's possible

Comment: @user13267 lol, you linked to a answer on this very question? Couldn't you say `look above this post`?